# Bottleneck while uploading lots of files to GCP bucket in a small time

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

So I have a GCP bucket and I have to upload files to it. The issue is I have 10 million files I want to upload into the bucket (each file size is 50kb) and I have a time constraint of 8 hours or fewer. Currently, I am using a Java program ([google ref code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java)) and tested it on 1000 images and it uploads each file in about 300 milliseconds, but if I use multi-threading; I have been able to reduce the average time to 40 milliseconds (using 20 threads). I can go up to 60 threads and reduce the time further to 15-20 milliseconds but then also I face 3 problems:

1. 20 milliseconds per file isn’t fast enough. I need it to be at least 3 milliseconds or fewer.
2. It throws “com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Connect timed out,” exception when I exceed 25 threads.
3. Going beyond 60 threads, the programs don’t seem to get any faster (I am guessing hardware constraint ).

Additional Info:

My internet speed is 700Mbps to 1.3 Gbps. I have thought about zipping and uploading but we have some constraint in that too so can’t use that approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the full path name pattern of your files?

Comment: On my local device:
driveletter\foldername\filename (e.g: I:\test\G00000B5_1608532119152.png )
On the GCP bucket:
bucketname\foldername\filename  (e.g: bucket_1\barcode11\G00000B5.png)

Comment: Ok, do you have an increment per file? something like `bucket_1\barcode11\G00000B6.png`

Comment: yes I do...all file uploaded are serial wise but it's not necessary they are uploaded in that manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. The answer by guillaume blaquiere made sense but that didn't solve my issue. My issue was that there was a large number of small files. To improve the performance I did the following:

1. I made zips of 1000 files (the logic behind 1000 explained at the end) which made each file to be approx 50-60 MB. That reduced my data set from 10 million files to 10000 files.
2. I used the GSUtil to upload the files into the bucket and used a cloud function that had a trigger tied to the bucket to unzip the files. Since cloud function can make multiple instances it handled the processing of multithreaded uploads easily. Each unzipping took me about 40-50 seconds which included unzipping and some other operations. Just unzipping will I assume will take somewhere between 20-30 seconds.
3. Uncommented and changed the following parameters in .boto (/Users/UserName/.boto) file:

   parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 120

   parallel_composite_upload_component_size = 50M

**Why I used 1000 files for zipping:**

parallel_composite_upload_component_size = 50M means that any file less than 50MB uploaded will not be broken down into chunks and 1000 files matched the threshold. I have tested on 1000,2000 and 5000 files zip and all of them takes the same amount of time relatively ( and also in each of the cases 100% of my bandwidth was being used; the time difference in each may be visible if I had higher bandwidth). And as for why 50M param, it's because on testing it was optimal for our use case.

**Conclusion:**

On testing this solution for 10000 zips (10 million files) I found that it consumed my entire bandwidth i.e 200 Mbps. and took about 7 hours to upload.

Comment: Did you try using gsutil? it supports parallel upload of a local directory.                                "gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my-bucket". 
  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#description

Comment: Sorry I meant gsutil when I wrote Gcloud Console. Corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might have an hotspot on Cloud Storage. You can't check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-XDw55qUzs) that explain you why and how to solve the issue, i.e. add a hash in your file name, before the sequential sequence.

Comment: It made sense and I tried doing it but I am still facing 'com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Connect timed out' caused by 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out'. My current file name has an SHA hash of the filename prepended to it (e.g: 04671296ce3ad5c092796ba39ea6d62c38f423f4_G00000aG.png) –
Once, it completed and it took about **40 millis** to upload each file which is the same as before (on 20 threads).
Also, I forgot to mention that these benchmarking tests I am performing on 1000 images, and do you think the average will get better with a larger dataset?